# Javascript: Exporting Data to a .txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I'm new to javascript and I wanted to know if I can export data into a txt file.
I can put the data in an alert but I want it to be downloaded onto the clients system as a txt file. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Similar question and answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43135989/4533488

Answer (score 3):

At the moment the [File API: Writer](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) is not ready, so you do not have direct interfaces to save file.

Still, you can create a link and put the text in the url.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(yourTextGoesHere);
link.innerHTML = 'Open the text file';
//set default action on link to force download, and set default filename:
link.download = 'some file name.txt';     

//now put the link somewhere in the html document:
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Written by hand and not tested. Should work, but might require debugging.

Edit:
added `download` attribute.

Comment: Is this possible to open savefile dialog asfter generate a file?

Comment: You can add `download="some file name.txt"` to force download the file, but most browsers will just download it, and not ask where to save the file. 
The FileWriter api I have mentioned here seems to be discontinued by W3C, and, while it is supported in Chrome, it might be dropped, so I would not use that. http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Answer (score 2):

Save text

```js
function save(text){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,' + escape(text);
    link.download = 'output.txt';
    link.click();
}
```